# How to pack code and folder become a installer

Tags: visual-c#-express-2010

I creating an windows forms application to configure IIS website application and also copy folder to selected location by user using visual c# 2010 express.
I want to pack the folder and application to become an executable file, like installer.
I can't find the setup template in Visual C# 2010 express.
Is there any way to pack the folder and the application to become an executable file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the method that i found is use winrar. It can pack files/folder that the application needed to run into an executable file.